# how to install zip extension in php 8.1 in Cyberpanel

Tags: zip, php-8.1, cyber-panel

In vps server Php 8.1 has no zip extension installed.

anyone help me to solve the problem.

Comment: I am also waiting for this answer. as my live production is on hold for last 2 months just cause of this issue.

Comment: Finally. I found the answer after search for hour. Good luck

Answer (score 3):

Follow below instructions for installing PHP extensions in CyberPanel for users who cannot find the desired extensions in the `Server > PHP > Install Extensions` section or in the LiteSpeed repository.

In such cases, you can use the PEAR package manager to manage PECL 17 extensions. First, change "lsphp81" to your default PHP version and run the following commands:

```
cd /usr/local/lsws/lsphp81/bin
wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
./lsphp go-pear.phar
```

Once PEAR is installed, you can install the required extension. For example, to install the latest version of the zip extension, use the following command:

```
/usr/local/lsws/lsphp81/bin/pecl install zip
```

If you need a specific version of the zip extension, you can install it using this command:

```
/usr/local/lsws/lsphp81/bin/pecl install zip-1.21.1
```

Note: Make sure to add `extension=zip.so` to your .php config

Remember to replace "lsphp81" with the PHP version you have installed as the default. This should help you install the PHP extensions you need in CyberPanel.