# "Zip Installed" set to "No" under "Server Environment" in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have been trying to figure this out for a week...have referenced countless articles and nothing seems to work. For some reason, Elementor shows "Zip Installed" is set to "No" under "Server Environment" and I cannot get this to update to "Yes."

I am all out of ideas and would truly appreciate any help you may all offer.

Server Environment
Operating System:   Linux
Software:   LiteSpeed
MySQL version:  MariaDB Server v10.4.31
PHP Version:    8.1.22
PHP Memory Limit:   512M
PHP Max Input Vars: 1000
PHP Max Post Size:  8M
GD Installed:   Yes
ZIP Installed:  No
Write Permissions:  All right
Elementor Library:  Connected

I have taken all the steps that were defined here: [how to install zip extension in php 8.1 in Cyberpanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75604360/how-to-install-zip-extension-in-php-8-1-in-cyberpanel)